# Automatically upload photo in Phonegap after taking picture with camera

Tags: android, upload, camera, cordova

Using PhoneGap's API for camera and file I am trying to make it so that when I take a photo in a certain app it is automatically uploaded to the server I'm using.

I have copied both of the API's into my index.html file and the only thing I changed is to add another javascript variable imageInfo that is set equal to ImageData in the block for onPhotoDataSuccess.  This imageInfo is then set as the parameter of uploadPhoto when I call it.

The only other thing I changed was to put the line:   `navigator.camera.DestinationType(1);` so that the output is the `imageURI` which is what `uploadPhoto` takes.

My only code in HTML is:

```
button onclick="capturePhoto(); uploadPhoto(imageData);">Capture Photo</button (in brackets of course)
```

But for some reason it isn't working.  Any tips or flaws you see in my reasoning?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could be a little more clear. Are you saying you want upload photos taken by an application other than your own?

Comment: I want the user to take a photo but then I want the application to automatically upload it right after it is taken.

Comment: Right but that doesn't answer my question: is your app taking the picture, or is another app taking the picture?

Comment: I am delegating the picture taking to the camera through the phonegap API but it is my app that does the delegation

Comment: @clifgray in the success call back of camera.getPicture() is where you want to call the FileTransfer.upload() code. You want to think more asynchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Camera is event-driven, you can't just chain events and hope for the best... In the `success` callback of the picture-taking code, you have to call **then** the code to upload the picture.

### EDIT

Here I am using the URI returned when successful to draw the image. But it should be pretty straightforward.

```
function takePicture() {
  loadPhotoIntake();
  navigator.camera.getPicture(
    setPicture,
    function(e) {
      console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
      document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Error getting picture.";
    },
    { quality: 70, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI});
};


function setPicture(uri) {
  var c=document.getElementById('camera_image');
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
  var img = new Image();
  var canvasCopy = document.createElement("canvas");
  var copyContext = canvasCopy.getContext("2d");
  var maxWidth, maxHeight;
  img.onload = function(){
    // resizing code
      .....
    // draw
    ctx.drawImage(canvasCopy, 0, 0, camera_image.width, camera_image.height);
  };
  img.src = uri;
}
```

Comment: Code example of success callback?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [FileTransfer API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer) will allow you to upload an image to your file server directly. (Assuming you are using the latest Phonegap)

This is exactly what you want. The source code taken from Phonegap's docs:

```
// Wait for PhoneGap to load
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
// PhoneGap is ready
function onDeviceReady() {
  // Retrieve image file location from specified source
  navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto,
  function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
    { quality: 50, 
      destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY }
    );
  }
  function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey="file";
    options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
    var params = new Object();
    params.value1 = "test";
    params.value2 = "param";
    options.params = params;
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(imageURI, "http://some.server.com/upload.php", win, fail, options);
  }
  function win(r) {
    console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
    console.log("Response = " + r.response);
    console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
  }
  function fail(error) {
    alert("An error has occurred: Code = " = error.code);
  }
```

Comment: yeah that is what I said I was using I just wanted to know where to put the call for FileTransfer.upload()

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you can use `camera.getPicture(...)` from the PhoneGap API. This will launch the default camera app, let the user take a picture, and when they are finished it will return either the data for the as a base64 encoded string, or it will give you the uri of the image file. You should then be able to use this to upload to the server. You can read more about `camera.getPicture` in the documentation found [here.](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html) It seems pretty straight forward from that article.

I have never used PhoneGap and I found this in 2 minutes.

Comment: yes I clearly realized that and said that I was using exactly that API in my code.  camera.getPicture doesn't have any uploading capability though.  I was wondering how to efficiently put that image URI into the File API code to upload it

Comment: I'm sorry, your code example above says `button onclick="capturePhoto(); uploadPhoto(imageData);">Capture Photo` not `camera.getPicture()`. I guess I don't understand what your question actually is then. Are you asking how to take a picture or how to upload a picture? The two tasks are entirely separate from each other and you will not find a magic API that does both at the same time.

Comment: \the question is how to take a photo and upload it once its taken.